# Git workflow for a CMS

Tags: git, version-control, merge, content-management-system, workflow

We have a CMS system, and currently with this workflow:

- We have one github repository for the whole CMS
- Each branch is representing website, and the master branch is where we develop new features - this has several advantages (we can compare the sites, version upgrade is only a merge, the CMS versions are maintainable)
- We store the site-specific folders on git too, because versioning is necessary for these folders as well

My first question is, that what is your opinion about this workflow? Is it a totally wrong way?

But we have some problems with this workflow.

- When we're upgrading a new version with a git merge (master -> site) the site specific folders are merged too, not only the core CMS files. I can Revert / Reset it after merge (and before commit), but it's not my favorite solution, a little bit complicated.
- Sometimes we develop a new feature for a site, and when it is finished, we merge it to the master, for a later new version. In this case after version upgrade merging we can see all of the site-specific commits in the git history. I know that this is how git works, it is only a small problem, but a little bit annoying.

I have some plans to solve it after reading on SO:

- Separate repository for the core CMS files, and the site specific folders
- Git submodule solution - it isn't clear for me yet, but maybe it is a better solution
- Playing with .gitattributes file, and with "merge=ours" config for site-specific folder - but if I know right, this is works only when the merge has conflict in the given directory.
- Other?

So what are your suggestions for this case?
I hope the situation is clear for you.
Thanks for the help :)

Adam

Answer (score 1):

`Separate repository for the core CMS files, and the site specific folders.`

This is what you should be doing, as your git history would benefit from the separation.

I would make a different repo for each one, and have it use your framework

Your workflow now:

```
W2 <- M -> W1
      |
      D
```

D - Development,
M - Master,
W - Webpage

Proposed Workflow:

```
W2  M  W1
|   |   |
D1  D2  D3
```

Where each `W`ebsite would grab `M`aster as a tool, not a git repo.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The suggested solution (different repos for sites) is the "normal" solution I think, but with this I can't compare site versions, files and others easily with git. 
I'm waiting for other tips a bit, but this is a good solution

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380019/git-merging-and-submodules

Maybe this will help. Make them submodules of the main CMS.